# Distinct on two columns (separately) and MIN on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I've tried to strip this problem down the the bare bones; I hope I've still captured the essence of what I'm trying to achieve in the original query!

- Code to generate the tables and data can be found [here](http://corley.co/sh.sql).
- SQL flavour is **Microsoft SQL Server 2000** (although I've been running this stripped down test case on MySQL)

**The original table**

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
| master_id | slave_id | distance |
+-----------+----------+----------+
|         1 |        1 | 0.1      |
|         1 |        3 | 10       |
|         2 |        2 | 3        |
|         3 |        2 | 2        |
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

**Description of what is required**

I would like to select `slave_id` `master_id` pairs with `MIN(distance)` with *no duplicates* of either `master_id` or `slave_id`.

**The desired results table**

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
| master_id | slave_id | distance |
+-----------+----------+----------+
|         1 |        1 | 0.1      |
|         3 |        2 | 2        |
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

**My Attempt**

```
SELECT
        join_table.master_id,
        join_table.slave_id,
        join_table.distance
    FROM join_table
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                slave_id,
                MIN(distance) AS distance
            FROM join_table
            GROUP BY slave_id
        ) AS self_join
    ON self_join.slave_id = join_table.slave_id
    AND self_join.distance = join_table.distance
```

**What's wrong with my attempt**

This query produces duplicates of `master_id`

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: how does `master_id` 2 get filtered out instead of `master_id` 3?

Comment: What do you mean "no duplicates of either master id or slave id"?  What violates this requitement?

Comment: @MattBusche by the MIN(distance) requirement

Comment: @MitchWheat I didn't include my attempt because it was very verbose and far too inefficient (it wouldn't run on the archive server due to timeout) if you really want me to post it then let me know

Comment: @GordonLinoff 2 rows with `master id = 1` would violate this requirement, as would 2 rows with `slave_id = 1`

Comment: @rgvcorley You should always show any attempt that you made at getting the result.

Comment: @bluefeet Apologies - I've added my attempt

Comment: @rgvcorley . . . This seems more like an optimization problem than a query problem.  What happens when two rows with the same id have the same minimum?

Comment: @GordonLinoff there will never be a duplicate unique pair of `slave_id` and `master_id`

Comment: @rgvcorley There's nothing wrong with the query you wrote - sounds like you need some indexes on your database

Comment: @MattBusche The query I wrote produces duplicates for `master_id` - apologies I wasn't clearer about this - I've updated the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes you're right it is an optimization problem - but this is an astronomical archive that I don't have the ability to edit the schema for and has a query timeout... I was wondering if there was a better/more efficient way to achieve what I've described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give the correct result:

```
select distinct t.master_id,
  t.slave_id,
  t.distance
from join_table t
inner join
(
  SELECT ID, min(Distance) dist
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT master_ID ID, MIN(distance) AS Distance
    FROM join_table
    GROUP BY master_ID
    UNION
    SELECT slave_ID ID, MIN(distance) AS Distance
    FROM join_table
    GROUP BY slave_ID
  ) src
  GROUP BY ID
) md
  on t.distance = md.dist
  and (t.master_id = md.id or t.slave_id = md.id)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f839/16)

Comment: Spot on, but it looks like I am going to have to find a way of getting a local copy of the tables to run the queries - the table in question has > 100 million records and there isn't an index on distance... needless to say the 3 hour limit on query time isn't enough...

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, here is what I would do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.master_id
   ,t.slave_id
   ,t.distance
FROM your_table t
   INNER JOIN 
   (
      SELECT master_id id, min(distance) distance
      FROM your_table
      GROUP BY master_id

      UNION

      SELECT slave_id id, min(distance) distance
      FROM your_table
      GROUP BY slave_id

   ) sub
   ON (sub.id = t.master_id AND sub.distance = t.distance)
     OR (sub.id = t.slave_id AND sub.distance = t.distance)
```